# Compilation failure when runs mvn jetty:run

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jetty, maven-3

I have tried to implement a simple chat application using Java and Jetty. I have followed all steps given below blog post.

[Blog Post](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/jetty/jetty-websocket-example/)

When I try to run mvn jetty:run I am getting below error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.0.2:compile (default-compile) on project sample_application: Compilation failure
[ERROR] /home/rajee/Documents/techZHomeSample/src/main/java/ToUpper356Socket.java:[12,1] error: annotations are not supported in -source 1.3
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

I have shared Java and Maven version that I have used below:

- Apache Maven 3.0.5
- Maven home: /usr/share/maven
- Java version: 1.7.0_03, vendor: Oracle Corporation
- Java home: /usr/local/jdk1.7.0_03/jre
- Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
- OS name: "linux", version: "3.13.0-76-generic", arch: "amd64",
  family: "unix"

Here You can find pom.xml below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.tech</groupId>
<artifactId>sample_application</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<properties>
    <jetty.version>9.2.11.v20150529</jetty.version>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${jetty.version}</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>


</build>

<dependencies>
    <!--Jetty dependencies start here -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
        <version>${jetty.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>${jetty.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--Jetty dependencies end here -->

    <!--Jetty Websocket server side dependencies start here -->



    <!--Jetty JSR-356 Websocket server side dependency -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.websocket</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax-websocket-server-impl</artifactId>
        <version>${jetty.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--Jetty Websocket API server side dependency -->
    <!--<dependency>-->
        <!--<groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.websocket</groupId>-->
        <!--<artifactId>websocket-server</artifactId>-->
        <!--<version>${jetty.version}</version>-->
    <!--</dependency>-->


    <!--Jetty Websocket server dependencies end here -->

    <!--Jetty Websocket client side dependencies start here -->



    <!--JSR-356 Websocket client side depencency  -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.websocket</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax-websocket-client-impl</artifactId>
        <version>${jetty.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--Jetty Websocket API client side dependency -->
    <!--<dependency>-->
        <!--<groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.websocket</groupId>-->
        <!--<artifactId>websocket-client</artifactId>-->
        <!--<version>${jetty.version}</version>-->
    <!--</dependency>-->
    <!--Jetty Websocket client side  dependencies end here -->

</dependencies>
```

Can anyone please help me to figure out what went wrong?

P.S - I am using IntelliJ Idea 14.1.3

As per request I have shared the error I got when I update the pom.xml as mentioned in answer.

```
java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:344)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:336)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:199)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.open(ServerConnector.java:321)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractNetworkConnector.doStart(AbstractNetworkConnector.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.doStart(ServerConnector.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.MavenServerConnector.doStart(MavenServerConnector.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:366)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyServer.doStart(JettyServer.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.startJetty(AbstractJettyMojo.java:534)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.execute(AbstractJettyMojo.java:357)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyRunMojo.execute(JettyRunMojo.java:167)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have got this error because Maven default is using JDK1.3 for the project compilation or building. Since JDK1.3 is not support annotation, if your project has annotation, you need to configure your Maven to use the latest JDK version.

As suggested above, you need to tell maven to run the latest version of JDK you have.